# How to print numbers in steps using function python

Tags: python

Am trying to write a function to print numbers in steps.Here is my code

```
def steps(num):
           v = num
           for i in range(1, v+1):
                print("   "*i + str(i)*3)
print(steps(3))
```

The result appears as

```
 111
      222
         333
None
```

I am trying to get rid of the "none" word any help? Note please, i don't want to get rid of the print statement in  "print(steps(3)), any other method or solution will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to output the spaces yourself like so:

```
for i in range(1, v + 1):
    print("    " * i + str(i) * 3)
```

Comment: I feel like you could golf this a bit... wait, wrong site ;)

Comment: @Wondercricket `print("\n".join("    "*i+str(i)*3 for i in range(1,v+1)))` (replace the space with 4 spaces but SE comments are dumb

Comment: I tried wrapping it in a function in order to call it, but is not working.

Comment: def steps(number):
           result = 3
           for i in range(1, result+1):
                return str(i)*3
       print steps(6)

Answer (score 1):

```
def steps(number): 
    mystr = ""
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        mystr += 3*str(i) + '\n' + i*'\t'
    return mystr
```